# kafka.common.KafkaException: Wrong request type 18

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running this piece of code.  The streamingInputDF is a readStream on a Kafka topic.  I am running spark 2.4.0 and Kafka 0.10.2

```
val activityQuery = streamingInputDF.writeStream
.format("console")
.outputMode("append")
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

I see this exception thrown by the Kafka broker as soon as the writeStream is invoked on streamingInputDF

```
[2018-11-24 21:46:42,842] ERROR Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
kafka.common.KafkaException: Wrong request type 18
    at kafka.api.RequestKeys$.deserializerForKey(RequestKeys.scala:64)
    at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
    at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please include the Kafka libraries you're using

Comment: This is my cmdline ./spark-shell --driver-class-path ~/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 --jars /Users/hadoop/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.2/libs/kafka-clients-0.10.2.2.jar,/Users/hadoop/spark-2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10/target/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar,/Users/hadoop/spark-2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10-sql/target/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar,/Users/hadoop/dev/twitter/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.3.jar,/Users/hadoop/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.2.2.jar,/Users/hadoop/twitter4j-stream-4.0.6.jar

Comment: If you use `--packages`, you don't need to duplicate that over to `--jars`, by the way, and your `spark-streaming-twitter` should probably be using version 2.4.0, if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.  I am now able to see the tweets in the spark shell as they flow into the Kafka topic.  All I did was restart the Kafka broker and nothing else changed.

```
val activityQuery = streamingInputDF.writeStream
.format("console")
.outputMode("append")
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```